# Lottery game with replacement

Tags: combinatorics

A state lottery game is played by selecting three numbers between $0$ and $9$, inclusive, with replacement. The winning numbers are selected in the same way. You win if your numbers match the winning numbers in any order.

Find the total number of ways the winning numbers can be selected.

How is the answer not $10^3=1000$ different ways?

Comment: To me it sounds as if the question is just asking ‘how many ways can the same three numbers be chosen?’ Which would be six.

Comment: @cluelessatthis apparently the answer is 220...

Answer (score 2):

A hint as to why the answer is not $10^3=1000$.

Suppose I pick $1,2,3$ as my numbers.

If the drawn numbers are $1,2,3$, I win.
If the drawn numbers are $1,3,2$, I win.
If the drawn numbers are $2,1,3$, I win.
If the drawn numbers are...

**Edit: A calculation.**

Of the $1000$ ordered draws:
$720$ contain three distinct numbers. (Example: $1,2,3$)
$270$ contain two numbers the same. (Example: $1,1,2$)
$10$ contain three numbers the same. (Example: $1,1,1$)

But for each category we need to eliminate equivalent draws:$$\frac{720}{6}+\frac{270}{3}+\frac{10}{1}=120+90+10=220.$$

Comment: Right, so there are 6 ways to match the winning numbers. OP, however, is suggesting that the correct answer is 220.

Comment: @cluelessatthis Yes. The point is that these $6$ draws are equivalent so you count them only as $1$.

Comment: right, I understand what you’re suggesting now.

Comment: @nickgard I see how if the winning numbers are 1,2,3, then I have 6 ways to choose winning numbers, but my prof is telling me the answer is 220 and with the wording of this question (verbatim), I dont understand how.